# Access Dynamic Page Props outside App Component

Tags: typescript, prisma, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am currently learning Next JS and I am using Next JS 13.4 with the new App Route. I have a Route like this: /user/[id]. My Problem is that I need to access this Prop in a custom Component I have created for the User. I cannot pass down the User Id to the Component from the Page because the Component will be created with the createElement Component.

I tried to use the Hoook useRouter from next/navigation as well as next/router but I cannot use it because it's not a Client Component. I need to have it as a Server Side Component because I am directly fetching Data from Prisma and for that I need the User Id.

Comment: You can pass props to `createElement` as a second argument. Does it solve your problem?